# Making DB Connection in file rather than following routes in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I am using few external libraries (for some reason, so i can't include it in routes)

The file is located at public/assets/manuacheck.php

I will be checking the file directly by domain.com/public/assets/manuacheck.php

(Don't care about security issue i will be having it only few few time)

There i use to following query

```
$users = DB::table('action')->where('Status', '0')->get();
```

Due to it is not  mentioned in the routes, i can't do any db actions here.

So, it's throwing the error

```
Fatal error: Class 'DB' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\yy\wrp\public\assets\manuacheck.php on line 616
```

Is that possible to establish the db connection here (I don't want to give the db credentials manually, but is it possible to establish the connection from database.php)

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't.

The framework hasn't boot up. If you want to use the framework you must make sure all request are handled by `public/index.php` (which starts by booting the framework) which is of course the default behaviour.
Otherwise you'd have to boot up the framework manually.

You can also use `Eloquent` out of Laravel, I found [this](http://jenssegers.be/blog/53/using-eloquent-without-laravel) haven't tested my self though.

Finally, you said you were trying to use some libraries: you must specify them in the `composer.json` that ships with Laravel. [Docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md).
And then run `composer update`. Then you can use routes and the query you tried to run will just work.

I hope this helps!